# Safely dilute this 35% hydrogen peroxide solution to 3% and store after opening (no stabilizer)?

Tags: home-experiment, safety

The problem: eating [yellow curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_curry) with [naan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naan) and no spoon for the first time resulted in a wonderful dinner but some permanent yellow stain on my cotton shirt. I assume it's coming at least in part from the [curcumin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curcumin) from [turmeric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmeric).

I've had some success removing bleach-resistant stains with household ~3% hydrogen peroxide. However that's surprisingly difficult to find where I live.

So I stopped by a chemistry supply shop, and they handed me a plastic bottle of 35% $\ce{H2O2}$ solution, specific gravity 1.196.

The Chinese writing on the label are common sense safety instructions (store away from light, not safe for food preparation, etc.).

Unlike household peroxide, and like some kinds of oxidizes in spacecraft ([Does the Soyuz spacecraft use chemically stabilized hydrogen peroxide (H₂O₂) to remain ISS-dockable for 200+ days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31337/12102)) the does not appear that there are any stabilizers in the solution.

**Question:** How can I safely dilute to 3%, and best store after opening this 35% hydrogen peroxide solution?

I plan to dilute enough for my present needs, and try to just screw the cap back on the rest of the bottle, but maybe there's more things to consider?

Click images for full size:

[image: 35% hydrogen peroxide H2O2] [image: cotton shirt stained by yellow curry]

Comment: The usual precautions are enough. Gloves are the must to prevent immediate whitening of the skin. If available also protecting glasses. Use clean jars or vessels to prevent catalytic violent decomposition.

Comment: @Poutnik and the usual precautions for diluting hydrogen peroxide would be...? If this is something I do usually I wouldn't need to post the question. The concentrated peroxide won't liberate oxygen over time and pressurize the bottle?

Comment: To the close voter, how might "How can I safely dilute to 3%, and best store after opening this 35% hydrogen peroxide solution?" *require clarity?* Why not add a comment and highlight what part isn't clear?

Comment: @uhoh, Oxygen bleaches only work in alkaline medium. Curry stain is a two pronged problem. You have oil and oil has dissolved curcuminoids from turmeric. First get rid oil by letting only dishwashing liquid on the stain overnight. After that rub that stain with lemon and keep washing the stain under warm water. Let sunlight work on it and it should be gone. Getting rid of oil is more important.

Comment: I have meant general usual precautions for manipulation with potentially harmful chemicals. Yes, it can pressurize the bottle. But it IS usually stabilized, AFAIK.

Comment: @Poutnik yes I'd never seen just pure H2O2 sold over the counter, albeit a chemistry supply counter. Maybe it's something I don't actually want to keep around for any long period of time at all, rather than worrying about how to store un-stabilized peroxide.

Comment: @AChem Thanks for that! I did hit it with water as soon as I'd noticed and worked in a lot of liquid soap soon after that, it's still in its dried-liquid-soap stage now. I'll continue with that procedure and luckily I have a friend with an all-day Sun-exposed roof who can give it a good dose. Hmm, but now I've got all this peroxide, maybe "How to have fun with 35% peroxide?" is my next question (humor).

Comment: @AChem your stain removal tutorial worked like a charm! :-)

Comment: @uhoh, Glad to know my proposed stain removing chemistry worked :-) I used to do these sun "bleaching" experiments during school days.